# How to create a background with a texture on Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 using XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I need to create a **backgroud** using a single image (100x100px) and repeat (using code) it on the screen (like a **texture**), how I can realize all of this?
A simple code:

```
<phone:Panorama>
    <phone:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush Strech="????" ImageSource="/img/texture.png"/>
    </phone:Panorama.Background>
</phone:Panorama>
```

**THE PROBLEM**:

[image]

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please, be more specific. Where is the problem with background?

Comment: The problem is that with the property **Strech** I can't repeat a image for create the background, and if I use a image 100x100px I can't fill the background.

Comment: @CinziaNicoletti I would suggest creating a MS Paint file of size 1920 x 1080p and copying pasting the 100 x 100 pixel image horizontally and verticall. Any one will be able to help you with that.

Comment: @kanchirk I need to spend less resources as possible, files that are too heavy are not expected.

Comment: I don't think WP has a TileMode ImageBrush equivalent. The workaround @kanchirk mentions is a viable one. Just make it a PNG and run it through some compression (something better than just Illustrator or Photoshop like [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/)) and you should be able to get the image down to like around 10k which isn't much.

Comment: Or also, since all you have are stripes, I could show you how to make that background with just XAML and no Image file real easy.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no options to tile `ImageBrush`, you should try to set the tiling background for panorama control via overrided panorama template. [Here is example with xaml code on a background](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2010/09/20/panorama-using-xaml-for-your-background.aspx). You can put the tiling image instead of xaml code.